# sql string produce error, cant determine if error is in the code or not

Tags: mysql

i have the following sql string.

```
SELECT * FROM `arriendos` WHERE CURRDATE() BETWEEN `inicio` AND `termino`
```

but i get MySQL said: Documentation 
 #1547 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted

i tried several times with the same error, and when i browse the table, all data seems to be ok and not corrupted. i created the table 1 hour ago.
do you have any idea if it is something fixeable or do i have to dump the table and make it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `CURDATE()` with one R, not `CURRDATE()`.

You can see it running in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51533/1